# Changed new hosting but remain the email features from old

Tags: dns, host, records

We have a new hosting to host our wordpress site.  But I would like to remain the email functionalities from my previous host.  So that our email users will never changed their local client settings.

If I changed the nameserver, the email of course will be in trouble.  I searched the net and found out it must somewhere in MX/Host Record.  So I redo the nameserver settings back to default and work around as what  suggested.  What I did recently is that I changed the 'www' address points to the shared IP of the new hosting server.

But when I visit my site after 24hrs.  It gives the page error "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Hope somebody can help here.

Thanks in advance,

Noie

Comment: I would go over all the redirects on your old and new server, double checking they are not redirected to them selves, or both to each other etc.

Comment: Just deleted all A records with '@' host name.  Have to wait 24hrs or more to get effect, right?

Comment: Well, it depends on the DNS TTL record, but as of experience a day seems to do it!

Comment: Just visit the page, the error now is different.  It says "could not find epitax.com".  Why is it?

Comment: That means the DNS server cant find the record. Might be that the DNS server isn't updated yet, but it's hard to say. If that's not the case, you'll need to add a record to `epitax.com`.

Comment: Ok! Have to wait some time for now.  If it still the same, I will add a record to epitax.com.  What I have in the host record now is 'www' points to the shared IP address of the new hosting.  Is that correct?

Comment: Sound reasonable! Good luck